# Why is IFormfile only converting first file into byte when I select Multiple Files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Using Asp.net Core 3.0.**

I am trying to upload multiple images to a database against one product converting it into byte form, but its only iterating through first selected file and converts it to Byte and saves only first file to database instead of iterating through each file and saving each file in database. On debugging it shows that its iterating through each item but it still saves only first item. There's no error, but I still cannot understand. Here is database screenshot.

[image: Image here]

Below is the code:

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ProductViewModel model, List<IFormFile> Images)
{
    try
    {
        var chheck = _context.Products.Include(x => x.Images);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var enter = new Product()
            {
                ProductCode = model.ProductCode,
                Price = model.Price,
                Title = model.Title,
                Description = model.Description,
                Type = model.Type,
                CatagoryId = model.CatagoryId
            };

            //   var prod = _context.Products.Where(x => x.ProductID == Product.ProductID.Value );

            if (model.Images != null && model.Images.FileName != "" && model.Images.FileName != null)
            {
                IFormFile file = model.Images;

                foreach (var imag in Images)
                {
                    if (imag.Length > 0)
                    {
                        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            Image img = new Image();
                            {
                                await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(stream);

                                img.FileName = file.FileName;
                                img.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                                img.ProductCode = model.ProductCode;

                                img.Pic = stream.ToArray();
                                stream.Close();
                                stream.Dispose();
                            };
                            _context.Images.Add(img);
                            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Index.cs Model Class**:

```
public class Image
{    
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ImageID { get; set; }

    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public byte[] Pic { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `imag` inside of your loop. Each iteration just loads the same `file` into the stream.

Comment: @Valuator do you mean it should be `imag.Pic=stream.ToArray();`

Comment: `await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(stream);` That is always the same file. Why are you using `file` rather than `imag`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that appear to be off with your action implementation. First of all, let’s take a look at its signature:

```
Task<IActionResult> Create(ProductViewModel model, List<IFormFile> Images)
```

It takes both a `ProductViewModel` and a `List<IFormFile>`. So you already have a custom model object but you still take the form files separately. I would suggest you to move the `IFormFile` list *inside* the view model itself, so that you only have a single parameter to your action method: The view model.

Within the action you then do this:

```
if (model.Images != null && model.Images.FileName != "" && model.Images.FileName != null)
{
    IFormFile file = model.Images;
```

So you *do* check the single `IFormFile` object called `Images` within your view model. Note that it is called plural “images” but is only a single `IFormFile`. So it can also only contain a single file.

```
foreach (var imag in Images)
{
    if (imag.Length > 0)
```

And then you loop through `Images`, the list of `IFormFile` objects. This would be where you get all the individual files to process. So each `imag` is one of the uploaded files.

However, what you actually end up processing within the loop is `file` which is `model.Images`, i.e. that *single* `IFormFile` object. So you should fix your code to actually work on that loop variable `imag` instead:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await imag.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(stream);

    Image img = new Image();    
    img.FileName = imag.FileName;
    img.ContentType = imag.ContentType;
    img.ProductCode = model.ProductCode;   
    img.Pic = stream.ToArray();

    _context.Images.Add(img);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: @ifrahnayyer Great! You’re welcome :) Please remember to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) if it solved your problem to mark the question as resolved.